# Beautifulsoup not working on a specific site

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse [this site](http://www.zap.com.br/imoveis/rio-de-janeiro+rio-de-janeiro/apartamento-padrao/venda/) and for reasons I can't understand, nothing is happening.

```
url = 'http://www.zap.com.br/imoveis/rio-de-janeiro+rio-de-janeiro/apartamento-padrao/venda/'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
doc = BeautifulSoup(response)
divs = doc.findAll('div')
print len(divs) # prints 0.
```

This site is a real-state ads in Rio de Janeiro, Brazil. I can't find anything in the html source that could prevents Beautifulsoup of working. Would it be the size?

I'm using Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.6, IPython Notebook 2.0, Beautifulsoup 4.3.2.

Comment: Same code worked perfectly for me, it displays 560...

Comment: Using the hint below, my enviroment only works with the 'html.parser' configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you are letting `BeautifulSoup` to choose the best suitable parser for you. And, this really depends on what modules are installed in your python environment.

According to the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use):

> The first argument to the BeautifulSoup constructor is a string or an
>   open filehandle–the markup you want parsed. The second argument is how
>   you’d like the markup parsed.
>
> If you don’t specify anything, you’ll get the best HTML parser that’s
>   installed. Beautiful Soup ranks lxml’s parser as being the best, then
>   html5lib’s, then Python’s built-in parser.

So, different parsers - different results:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> url = 'http://www.zap.com.br/imoveis/rio-de-janeiro+rio-de-janeiro/apartamento-padrao/venda/'
>>> import urllib2
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
>>> len(BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml').find_all('div'))
558
>>> len(BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser').find_all('div'))
558
>>> len(BeautifulSoup(response, 'html5lib').find_all('div'))
0
```

The solution for you would be to specify a parser that can handle parsing of this particular page, you may need to install [`lxml`](http://lxml.de) or [`html5lib`](https://github.com/html5lib).

Also see: [Differences between parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers).

Comment: Interesting. I thought the difference between the parsers was just speed. I take it the default parser is the most tolerant then ?

Comment: @dilbert if you are speaking about `html.parser`, then it depends on the python version, in case of 2.7, yup, it's more tolerant than before. `html5lib` should be the most lenient here, but, as you see, it cannot parse the page correctly.

Comment: @alecxe I have already tried lxml and html5lib parser, and getting the same result, nothing at all. But with the html.parser, which I didn't know, it worked fine. Could it be the Entought distribution the cause of the problem? Anyway, as with the html.parser it works, I can finally move on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your environment, Here is the output I get:

```
>>> url = 'http://www.zap.com.br/imoveis/rio-de-janeiro+rio-de-janeiro/apartamento-padrao/venda/'
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import urllib2
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
>>> doc = BeautifulSoup(response)
>>> divs = doc.findAll('div')
>>> print len(divs) # prints 0.
558
```

Comment: What would you suggest me to look for? I have no idea what's wrong in my enviroment.